# Delete a dynamic array but keep a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have made a function for expanding array, and this function is inside a class.

Because this function creates `new_arr` and copies all the numbers of `array` into the `new_arr` and at the end sets pointer of `array` with `new_arr`, I wold like to know how to delete numbers in `array` becuse I dont need it any more

```
void Array::bigger() {
    int  new_size = size * 2;
    int *new_arr = new int[new_size];
    for (int f1=0; f1<last; f1++) {
        new_arr[f1] = array[f1];
    }
    this->size = new_size;
    array = new_arr;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `delete[] array;` before `array = new_arr;`. You could also use `std::copy()` to copy `array` to `new_arr`. You could also use `std::vector<int>` and forget about dynamic memory management.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is an exercise, then delete the array before re-assigning to the new one:

```
delete [] array;
array = new_arr;
```

In real code, use an `std::vector<int>` instead of the dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 3):

free memory before lose pointer to it:

```
void Array::bigger() {
    int  new_size = size * 2;
    int *new_arr = new int[new_size];
    for (int f1=0; f1<last; f1++) {
        new_arr[f1] = array[f1];
    }
    this->size = new_size;
    delete[] array; //free memory
    array = new_arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is so simple