# Can I delete a pointer but keep the variable

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

Can someone provide me the answer to the question posted below.

The implement is same as the one the question question on this post

[Delete a dynamic array but keep a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415572/delete-a-dynamic-array-but-keep-a-pointer/61065547#61065547)

Could I then delete the new_arr? Or is that automatically taken care of?

if I were to delete it would i use:

`delete [] new_arr;`

`delete new_arr;`

?

Comment: Please copy-paste the implementation to this question. Reducing the number of clicks to see your full question will increase response rate.

Comment: All questions here must have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors, shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. This question must be [edit]ed, and all links and images removed and replaced with all relevant information, as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text. There's no reason why this one can't, either.

Comment: Also please make clear why the answers to that linked question do not answer your question here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a dynamic array but keep a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415572/delete-a-dynamic-array-but-keep-a-pointer)

Comment: the answer you link to is deleted, hence not everybody can see it

Answer (score 2):

You don't "delete a pointer", you delete some object that you allocated, specifying which object to be deleted by providing a pointer to it.

When you allocate an object with `new`, you free it with a call to `delete`. These calls must match 1-to-1 and the value you pass to `delete` must be the value you got from `new`.

Analogously, for arrays, you use `new[]` and `delete[]`, again matching them 1-to-1.

After `delete [] new_arr;`, the value in `new_arr` is invalidated as it points to an object that no longer exists. Calling `delete new_arr;` would be an error because the value you are passing does not point to an object allocated by `new`, so there is no object you need to free.